# How to sort words in text file?

Tags: python

In "test_wordss.txt"

```
A
sentence
is
a
grammatical
unit
consisting
of
one
or
more
words
A
```

My code:

```
for line2 in open('C://Users/Desktop/test_wordss.txt'):
    fields2 = line2.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    print fields2.sort()
```

The results from my codes come out as None...

Did I do something wrong? 
Any suggestion for sorting words in text file?

Comment: [A helpful link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440612-sort-a-file/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
words = sorted(open('C://Users/Desktop/test_wordss.txt').read().split())
print(words)
```

There are several problems with your code:

1. `sort()` doesn't return the sorted list. It sorts the list in place, and returns `None`.
2. Your code attempts to sort the words in each line, and there's only one word per line. It doesn't attempt to work on the entire file at once.

Comment: Nice one! Good answer, explaining what is wrong with his code.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` sorts the list in-place [(doc)](http://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and returns `None` to make that point (so you don't forget about the side-effect you only get the side-effect).  Either use

```
print sorted(fields2)
```

or

```
fields2.sort()
print fields2
```

Comment: Great answer! Stands out from the others in that it explains and helps without providing too much raw code without any explanation.

Answer (score 0):

`sort` doesn't return a `sorted` list, it `sort` the list in place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for line in sorted(file('C://Users/Desktop/test_wordss.txt').read().split("\n")):
    print line
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in word_list:
    ordered = True
    last = ord(x[0])
    
    for char in x[1:]:
        if ord(char) < last:
            flag = False
            break
        last = ord(char)
    
    if ordered:
        print(word)
```